# Component nested in app.component breaks app

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a component in another component. However when I add the nested component (ticket-adder) it breaks my app. ie all I get is the "loading..." nothing else loads.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { TicketAdderComponent } from './ticket-adder.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TicketAdderComponent],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello There, I\'m Angular2</h1>
                </br>
                <ticket-adder></ticket-adder>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

ticket-adder.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'ticket-adder',
    template: '<h1>Ticket Adder</h1>'
})

export class TicketAdderComponent { }
```

ETA: Error Log added

```
(index):16 Error: (SystemJS) Template parse errors:(…)(anonymous function) @     (index):16
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203
Zone.run @ zone.js:96 (anonymous function) @ zone.js:462
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="libs/core-js/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/zone.js/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/systemjs/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

ETA 2: I've noticed that visual studio is reporting this error " Cannot find module './tags'." in parser.d.ts in Angular/Core

Comment: what is error log ?

Comment: Where do I find the error log?

Comment: browser console (F12)

Comment: What does "it breaks my app" mean exactly?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/aCCJr81fQTOPKA5wyKt6?p=preview is plunker of your code  which works

Comment: can you post index.html ?

Comment: Post updated with error log, and index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the the `</br>` tag in the template was the problem. Once I removed it. Everything started working.

@anshuVersatile example didn't have the  tag in it so it worked.

working code

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello There, I\'m Angular2</h1><ticket-adder></ticket-adder>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```